# after minimizing a window, should it then be the default window?

Tags: favorites

This seems wrong. I have 3 terminal windows open, windows A, B, and C. I have window A front-most.

I click on the "Minimize" button on window A. None of the terminal windows are now front-most.

I click on the Terminal icon in the Favorites.

What should be the behavior here? I think i just put terminal window A away, saying "I do not want to look at this." But when I click on the Terminal icon in the Favorites, I get terminal window A. Why?

I would expect to get terminal window B or C.

Should the system know my intention here? I just said "please minimize this window". That seems very clear. Why is the system ignoring my clearly expressed intentions? Which software is doing this?

I end up having to bring window B front-most, then click on window A, then minimize window A, then click on window B and, now, when I click on the Terminal icon, it will show me something other than window A.

Comment: Window A is the last one you clicked, so it's "most recent." If you want different behavior, submit a feature request or install an extension.

Comment: It's clear you have a strong preference, but it's much less clear that it's a demonstration of intent that should apply to everybody. I know people who minimize in order to see something behind the current window...but they still consider the minimized window to be "current". UX designers get into too many barfights over questions like these, so I stopped going to those bars.

Comment: Esther - do you have a suggestion for getting started with the gnome desktop code? I am willing to do it. And I am willing to figure it our myself. But if anyone has a suggestion, I would be glad to hear it.